# A Simpler Way to Code This Stackengine Asterism

Tags: stacking-symbols, stackengine, stack

Consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\asterism{\par\vspace{1em}{\centering\scalebox{1.5}{%
  \stackon[-0.5pt]{*}{\stackon[-0.5pt]{\stackon[-0.5pt]{*}{*~*~*}}{*}}}\par}\vspace{.5em}\par}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\vspace*{20pt}
\asterism
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

I have often used the `stackengine` package, but am still encountering difficulty with some of the logistics---undoubtedly, my fault. In this case, though I have produced the cross-shaped asterism I was looking for, it seems to me that there may be a much more efficient way of coding it.

QUESTION: Can anyone suggest (perhaps using `stackengine`) a simpler way of coding this asterism?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you need any package here.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\def\asterism{\begin{center}
\shortstack{*\\[-2pt]*\,*\,*\\[-2pt]*\\[-2pt]*}    
  \end{center}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\vspace*{20pt}
\asterism
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's hard to imagine a simpler answer than this. Thank you.

Comment: I think you want the vertical spacing to match the horizontal, and it doesn't.

Comment: @barbarabeeton you could squeeze it more than `[-2pt]` vertically or use some horizontal space a bit bigger than `\,`

Answer (score 4):

You can try Ti*k*Z or the following method using primitive alignments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\asterism}{%
  \par\nopagebreak\vspace*{20pt}
  \noindent\makebox[\columnwidth]{%
    \vbox{%
      \offinterlineskip
      \tabskip=0.4ex
      \halign{%
        &##\cr % template
        &$*$\cr\noalign{\vskip0.5ex}
        $*$&$*$&$*$\cr\noalign{\vskip0.5ex}
        &$*$\cr\noalign{\vskip0.5ex}
        &$*$\cr
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \par\vspace{20pt}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]

\asterism

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Vertical spacing between asterisks should match the horizontal, and it doesn't.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Better now? Of course it depends on fonts used, so adjustments will be needed for other fonts.

Comment: Yes, better.  thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Since all baselineskips are identical between the lines of the stack, you can just use a `\Longstack`, with the long-stackgap set to the desired value, here 0.75em.  I show your version, then my revision, for comparison.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\oldasterism{\par\vspace{1em}{\centering\scalebox{1.5}{%
  \stackon[-0.5pt]{*}{\stackon[-0.5pt]{\stackon[-0.5pt]{*}{*~*~*}}{*}}}\par}\vspace{.5em}\par}
\def\asterism{\par\vspace{1em}{\setstackgap{L}{.75em}\centering
  \scalebox{1.5}{\Longstack{* *~*~* * *}}\par}\vspace{.5em}\par}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\vspace*{20pt}
\oldasterism
\asterism
\end{document}
```

[image]